# “404 not found” error on wordpress posts after click

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, http-status-code-404, posts

I have developed a wordpress theme and I have posted some posts but Whenever i click on any post then I am getting "404 not found" , "The requested URL /wordpress/demo-post/ was not found on this server." . Since i new to wordpress development so I am not able to solve this issue .

Please suggest how I can solve this .

Answer (score 0):

This is often down to permalinks not being set correctly. In the admin area, head to Settings->Permalinks, choose a style and hit save. Then confirm that your `.htaccess` file contains this at the top:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```